# UIView subclass creating its own UIButtons

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton, subclass, drawrect

I have subclassed UIView so I can draw some lines in it. In this UIView are a whole bunch of buttons which I decided to create as a method that drawRect calls after the lines are drawn. It works but sometimes only part of the button renders. If i remove the button creation and instead add the UIButton in the subclassed UIViews parent it works fine.

Is doing things like adding subviews in drawRect method a big no no or should I not do it all together in UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yea that's a pretty big no no. drawRect is for adding stuff with CG, not views. It gets called repeatedly and unpredictably. Adding them in initWithFrame should be pretty safe though.

Comment: or initWithCoder if you are setting up the view in interface builder